# Проектирование БД, под СРМ систему

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, mariadb, innodb

Есть один вопрос, пишу срм систему в которой зарегатся может каждый, и при регистрации ему создается магазин, так вот вопрос в том как хранить допустим товары,заказы под каждый магазин? Создавать под каждый магазин новую БД? Или лучше допустим в таблице товаров просто добавлять id магазина которому принадлежит этот товар?

Comment: Второй вариант - [реляционная база данных](https://metanit.com/sql/tutorial/)

Comment: @Serge-V зачем ты челу скинул документацию на sql? :D он просто спросил держать товары клинтов в одной базе или в разных. На этот вопрос в принципе нельзя дать объективный ответ. Ибо есть куча факторов которые будут влиять на этот выбор. Но твой коммент прямо все ему объяснил, аргументировано и со смыслом :D

Comment: @ВадимАлександру :D
Ну да. Я думал, достаточно одной бд. 
В общем, дождусь толкового ответа и буду просвещаться вместе с автором вопроса